# How does Grid design helps and what are their roles in Website Design

Tags: website-design, grids

I'm not a designer but I'm learning how to implement an efficient design on a website. How do we decide on the grid used, as far as I can grasp, 3x3 boxes looks good to me. But as I keep reading, i noticed there are many more grid variations such as 12x12, 16x16. If so, where will the "focus" point lie in the website?

In a 3x3 Grid, I understand that the "focus" point lies between the two horizontal line intersecting with one of the vertical line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grid is simply a tool used to give visual balance to a piece. There's nothing stating that anyone has to follow or not-follow a grid in anything. Its just there to help with layout.

The grids you give all could work, but its really up to what YOU think looks good. If you work in only 3x3 grids and you and your client are happy with the results, then you don't really need to worry about the other grids. If you find that other grid formats, even grids with different row-column lengths (like a 3x5 grid or 5x7 grid, for example) then more power to you.

And you say you understand that the focus on a 3x3 grid lies where the grid lines cross; this could be said about any grid you are giving. Theoretically andy point on a grid where the lines cross could be a focus point on your piece. It just depends on how you place your elements and what hierarchy you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that means grid is only a meant for the visual balance and in order to have certain focus on the website layout, i'll need to couple with other criteria as well. Am I right? More complex grids are meant for more complicated arrangement of boxes.

Comment: A more complex grids COULD be for more complex desings. But the more complex the grid the less help it will be. A 24x24 grid probably won't help you at all with your layout as a 3x3 grid would (but you would probably find that your 24x24 grid would just be reduced to a 6x6, 4x4 or 3x3 grid anyways).